# Wiki Home Page add Webparts

Tags: 2013, powershell, wiki-pages

How can I add a WebPart with Powershell to a Wiki Home Page which was created with the site feature "Wiki Page Home Page" to a specific "zone"?

I'm using the text layout "Two columns with header and footer" and I want to place e.g. a promoted links list i the left column and views of the document library in the right column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiki pages do not have zones; web parts are placed inline with the text content. You can either use a Web Part Page instead of a Wiki Page, or you could programmatically reference the `<div>` tags in your Wiki Page content.